# How to secure blum cabinet hinge (Blum 74559)

Tags: kitchens, screws, hardware

I have a Blum 74559 hinge that's falling off the door due to heavy use. This hinge is originally part of an Ikea kitchen system. The original installer didn't use any screws to fasten the hinge to the door - it was just pressure fit in. But that's not working now as the door is falling off with use. Now I need to properly install it, presumably using screws. There are predrilled holes in the door that the little metal sleeves slip into, and there are also other holes on the door side of the hinge that could be used if I drill the door. I found the original manual for these but they don't show any additional screws being used.

Does anyone know the recommended fastener for this application?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are actually pressure fit hinges- see the flanges on each side of the part that fits in the door hole-. I have seen them before but have forgotten what actuates the spread on those wings. Possibly a replacement would work better than this one but, it seems your particle board doors have worn the hole a bit larger than it should be. Try with 5/8" screws.

Comment: @Kyle when you close the cover that expands the "wings". The cover is open in the first pic and looks like it is closed in the last pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the predrilled hinge holes on the inside (close to the vertical middle) -- 1/2" #8 wood screws which fit perfectly inside the cover panel. Yes, the other holes towards top and bottom are for the alignment sleeves. I did have to drill holes into the door.

Answer (score 1):

This hinge may have been installed as a press-fit, but it wasn't *supposed* to have been installed that way. Someone just didn't finish the job.

Take the hinge to a local retailer (a local hardware store, a woodworking store like Rockler or Woodcrafters, or even a big-box home improvement store) and find screws that will go through these holes in the hinge:

[image: OPs hinge image with arrows indicating where screws should go]

and into these pre-drilled holes in the cabinet door:

[image: OPs door image with arrows indicating where screws should go]

Usually the screws have a flat head, a tapered under side (this is called a "bugle head" or "flat head" screw) and a very coarse thread with a flat bottom. The flat head and tapered side will fit nicely into the counter sunk recess in the hinge, and the coarse threads and flat bottom hold well in the particle board of the door. You do *not* want a pointed tip wood screw (likely to go right through the face of the door), nor do you want a machine screw (the fine threads will not get a good bite in the particle board and will pull out).

Generally, the screws will come with the hinges, but a well stocked hardware store or a woodworking specialty store should be able to come up with something. You *might* find them at a big box store, or you may have to buy a hinge just for the screws.

Since you know that it's a Blum hinge, you may try contacting them via their web site to find out where you can buy (locally or online) replacement screws, as those would be sure to fit your application.

---

I'd suggest that since the screws weren't installed in this hinge, it's likely that they're missing from all the hinges and that the rest of them are just one good slam away from popping out of their press-fit just as this one did. Now's as good a time as any to check the rest and buy enough screws to finish the job that the previous person left undone.

Comment: Those are sort of "press fit". Notice OP's 3rd picture, the ears expand to grab in the receiving hole. The way you get them to expand is by closing the decorative cover that covers the screw holes. Note the worn out area of the receiving hole in the door matches the "ears" on the hinge. My guess is the hinge was never full seated in the receiving hole when they installed it. Seeing that the hole is deformed yours is the best answer unless OP wants to try and repair the receiving hole in the door.

Comment: Those pre drilled holes are to line the hinge up when you install it, if you look carefully there's a pilot on the hinge that goes in the pre drilled  hole in the door. I'd use the other holes in the plate and carefully drill a pilot hole in the door and follow the advice in your answer as far as right size screws.

Answer (score 0):

Drill in the spare metal of the hinge and add two screws.

Done that before.

Comment: Based on visually aligning the hinge holes and the two holes in the door, it appears that the two uncountersunk holes might align with the door holes, but the countersunk hinge holes are undrilled in the door. Drive two screws in the countersunk hinge holes, no need to drill new holes.

Answer (score 0):

Companies like Rockler sell repair plates. For installing these style hinges on damaged or worn doors. You can google, "Cabinet repair plates" They can be found on Amazon as well.

Comment: What kind of "repair plate" should the OP be looking for? What is to be repaired?

Comment: Should this have been a comment on another answer, or is it just badly incomplete?

Comment: Oddly enough, that search term yielded an appropriate result on the first page. However, and it's a big however, those are fugly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it might be of interest to other people in the future.

I have done a fair bit of repair on these sort of hinges. For doors with light use, filling the two screw holes is enough. If you would like to make a more permanent fix, or the door see heavier use, I suggest filling the dowel holes partly with wooden dowels and plain wood glue. This can accommodate another pair of screws. Adding some wood glue to the worn sides where the expansion lugs engage will also cause the wooden fibres to expand a little, adding to the overall result.